# Query between datetime SQLAlchemy for backref

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

How can I filter `bookings` between 2 dates when bookings are a property of a `plane`:

```
planes = Plane.query.all()
```

The `plane` has a backref to bookings

```
plane_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('plane.id'))
plane = db.relationship('Plane', backref=db.backref('bookings', lazy='dynamic'))
```

`booking` has a start and end datetime:

```
start_date = db.Column(db.DateTime)
end_date = db.Column(db.DateTime)
```

How can I filter bookings to a specified day so planes only include the filtered bookings?

Answer (score 2):

Something Like [querying with joins](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#querying-with-joins)?

```
session.query(
    Plane
).join(
    Bookings
).filter(
    Bookings.start_date >= start_date,
    Bookings.end_date <= end_date
).all()
```

Comment: @amiawizard Oops! Replace `=>` with `>=` !!

Answer (score 0):

1. 'start_date' and 'end_date' is of type datetime.datetime
2. convert them to string(it becomes like '2020-06-23 19:40:33'):

   *. start_date = Bookings.start_date.isoformat(' ', 'seconds')

   *. end_date = Bookings.end_date.isoformat(' ', 'seconds')
3. get current date as:
   currenct_date = datetime.datetime.now().isoformat(' ', 'seconds').
4. session.query(Plane).join(Bookings)
   .filter(currenct_date.between(Bookings.start_date, Bookings.end_date).all()